# pytorch layer input, output shape calculation

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Can anyone help me to understand when I use conv1d and then a linear layer, What will be the inputs of the linear layer? How to calculate how many input features should I have to pass in pytorch

Answer (score 1):

In Pytorch, Linear layers operate using only the last dimension of the input tensor: `[*features_in]` -> `[*,features_out]`.

However, Conv1D layers consider the last 2 dimensions of the input tensor: `[batches,channels_in, length_in]` -> `[batches,channels_out, length_out]`.

Therefore, if no pre-processing is used, Linear layers will only work with the signals defined for every channel, i.e., `[batches,channels_in,features_in]` -> `[batches,channels_in,features_out]`. This behavior is rarely desired, so people usually flatten tensors before passing them to a Linear layer. For example, it's common to use `Linear(x.view(n_batches,-1))`.

The behavior you need depends on the details of your application. Good luck,

Sources:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html (Conv1d)
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html (Linear)